# Transform .txt file to JSON via XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following .txt file that contains sample data like:

```
january,february,march
1,2,3
```

I am using the following code to first transform the .txt file into XML and then transform it to JSON.

The XML transformation gives me the following output:

```
<Sales>
   <Month>
      <january>1</january>
      <february>2</february>
      <march>3</march>
   </Month>
</Sales>
```

And I am trying to have this output in JSON in the following format:

```
{
    "Month": [
        {
            "january": "1",
            "february": "2",
            "march": "3"
        }
}
```

The code I am using is the following, which is fine up until the XML part, but not the JSON transformation part.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common" extension-element-prefixes="exsl"
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" xmlns:fcn="http://www.re.com/2018/local-functions"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs fn fcn exsl" version="3.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:param name="csv-encoding" as="xs:string" select="'iso-8859-1'"/>
    <xsl:param name="csv-uri" as="xs:string" select="'/Users/user/Desktop/so.csv'"/>
    <xsl:template match="/" name="csv2xml">
        <Sales>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="unparsed-text-available($csv-uri, $csv-encoding)">
                    <xsl:variable name="csv" select="unparsed-text($csv-uri, $csv-encoding)"/>
                    <!--Get Header-->
                    <xsl:variable name="header-tokens" as="xs:string*">
                        <xsl:analyze-string select="$csv" regex="\r\n?|\n">
                            <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                                <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                                    <xsl:copy-of select="tokenize(.,',')"/>                                        
                                </xsl:if>
                            </xsl:non-matching-substring>
                        </xsl:analyze-string>
                    </xsl:variable>                    
                    <xsl:analyze-string select="$csv" regex="\r\n?|\n">
                        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                            <xsl:if test="not(position()=1)">
                                <Month>
                                    <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(.,',')">
                                        <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
                                        <xsl:element name="{$header-tokens[$pos]}">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                        </xsl:element>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                </Month>
                            </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
                    </xsl:analyze-string>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:variable name="error">
                        <xsl:text>Error reading "</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$csv-uri"/>
                        <xsl:text>" (encoding "</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$csv-encoding"/>
                        <xsl:text>").</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:message><xsl:value-of select="$error"/></xsl:message>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$error"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </Sales>
        <xsl:variable name="transformed-xml">
            <array xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
                <xsl:for-each select="Month">
                    <map>
                            <string key="id">
                                <xsl:value-of select="./january" />
                            </string>
                    </map>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </array>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="xml-to-json($transformed-xml, map {'indent': true()})" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Is that CSV only having that one line of data? If there can be several lines I fail to see how the chosen JSON (top-level `{ "Month":`) could work. Also in the XSLT you are creating a top-level `array` for the XML representation of the JSON. As for the month data, you seem to want to process `Month/*` at use `local-name()` for the `key` attribute.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, this is actually just a sample, but of course, there will be multiple rows. Could you please help me out with the syntax of what you described?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the transformation of the XML you create to the XML representation you can feed to `xml-to-json` I would suggest an approach like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:variable name="xml-rep-of-json">
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:value-of select="xml-to-json($xml-rep-of-json, map { 'indent' : true() })"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Sales">
      <array>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </array>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Month">
      <map>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </map>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Month/*" expand-text="yes">
      <string key="{local-name()}">{.}</string>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

On the JSON side it creates a top level array containing unnamed JSON objects/maps with named string properties containing the data e.g.

```
 [ 
    { "january" : "1",
      "february" : "2",
      "march" : "3" },

    { "january" : "1",
      "february" : "2",
      "march" : "3" } ]
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ej9EGdp/2

To combine that with the first step to convert the CSV data into XML you could use

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:param name="csv-string" as="xs:string">january,february,march
1,2,3
1,2,3
1,2,3
</xsl:param>

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:variable name="csv-data-as-xml">
        <Sales xmlns="">
            <xsl:variable name="csv" select="$csv-string"/>
                    <!--Get Header-->
                    <xsl:variable name="header-tokens" as="xs:string*">
                        <xsl:analyze-string select="$csv" regex="\r\n?|\n">
                            <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                                <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                                    <xsl:copy-of select="tokenize(.,',')"/>                                        
                                </xsl:if>
                            </xsl:non-matching-substring>
                        </xsl:analyze-string>
                    </xsl:variable>                    
                    <xsl:analyze-string select="$csv" regex="\r\n?|\n">
                        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                            <xsl:if test="not(position()=1)">
                                <Month>
                                    <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(.,',')">
                                        <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
                                        <xsl:element name="{$header-tokens[$pos]}">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                        </xsl:element>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                </Month>
                            </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
                    </xsl:analyze-string>
        </Sales>          
      </xsl:variable>

      <xsl:variable name="xml-rep-of-json">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="$csv-data-as-xml/node()"/>
      </xsl:variable>

      <xsl:value-of select="xml-to-json($xml-rep-of-json, map { 'indent' : true() })"/>

  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Sales">
      <array>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </array>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Month">
      <map>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </map>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Month/*" expand-text="yes">
      <string key="{local-name()}">{.}</string>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ej9EGdp/3

Comment: Thank you so much for this. it's amazing work. I have one question, if possible. If I try to use pipe as a delimiter, if I change this line of code ````<xsl:for-each select="tokenize(.,',')">```` to ````<xsl:for-each select="tokenize(.,'|')">```` it won't work, do I need to escape the pipe somehow?

Comment: @Site, yes, the second argument is a regular expression where the pipe is a meta character normally used to separate alternatives so to use it literally you need to escape it in XPath as `\|`.

Comment: Thanks again for this!